# Context issue in IHttpHandler

Tags: vb.net

Sorry, this can be a basic question for advanced VB.NET programmers but I am a beginner in VB.NET so I need your advice.

I have a web application and the login is required for some specific pages. To check if the user is logged in, the old programmer used this technique:

```
 Dim sv As New WL.SessionVariables(Me.Context)

    If Not (sv.IsLoggedIn) Then
        Response.Redirect(WL.SiteMap.GetLoginURL())
    End If
```

Well, I have to use this Logged In checking in a handler done by me and I tried this:

```
Public Class CustomHandler
    Implements System.Web.IHttpHandler, IReadOnlySessionState

    Sub ProcessRequest(ByVal context As HttpContext) Implements IHttpHandler.ProcessRequest
        Dim sv As New WL.SessionVariables(context)
        If Not (sv.IsLoggedIn) Then
            context.Response.Write("No access unless you're the CEO!!!" & sv.IsLoggedIn)
        ElseIf sv.IsLoggedIn Then
            DownloadFile(context)
        Else
        End If
    End Sub 
   //other code
End Class
```

Well, the "is logged in" checking is always false (even after I login) and *I think it's an issue with the context*. So all the other pages works fine with logging checking but **this handler have this specific issue.**

Can you guys give a helping hand?

**UPDATE**:

The logged in is done trough this method:

```
Public Sub SetCreditialCookie(ByVal accountID As Integer)
        Me.AccountID = accountID
        m_context.Session.Item("loggedInAccount") = accountID

        m_context.Response.Cookies.Add(New System.Web.HttpCookie("account_id", CStr(m_context.Session.Item("account_id"))))
        m_context.Response.Cookies("account_id").Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(5)
    End Sub
```

and to check it it's logged in, this method is called:

```
Public Function IsLoggedIn() As Boolean
        If Not m_context.Session.Item("loggedInAccount") Is Nothing And Me.AccountID = m_context.Session.Item("loggedInAccount") Then
            Return True
        Else
            Return False
        End If
    End Function
```

**UPDATE 2:**
- debugging the code shown that there were multiple kind of logins and I was checking the wrong one with the session.

Answer (score 0):

Due to the use of `IReadOnlySessionState`, is it possible that the `SessionVariables` class attempts in some way to modify the Session, which in turn causes an error (possibly handled and not visible to you).

If this is the case it could mean that the IsLoggedIn property is not correctly initialised, or does not function as expected?

Do you have access to the code for the class. If so, try debugging it to see what is happening.

Comment: Thanks jdavies. I've updated my question with the code for doing login. Do you see anything wrong which can cause conflicts as you said?

Comment: Wehn pressing the Login button: `sv.SetCreditialCookie(accountID)`

Comment: Have you tried debugging the code? That way you can determine exactly what is causing the issue. Is the `loggedInAccount` Session variable null? Also what is the call to `Me.AccountID` doing?